# Qemu Debian x86 on RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu

I want to create `i386` environment with `QEMU` and `chroot` on Raspberry Pi.
I am using Raspberry Pi ver B, but I guess it should not matter much which version is used.

So far I did:

```
apt-get install qemu qemu-user qemu-user-static binfmt-support debootstrap binutils
```

Then I mounted `chroot` directory to `/tmp/mnt` and ran:

```
sudo debootstrap --foreign --arch i386 buster  ./ http://deb.debian.org/debian/
```

Then I mounted:

```
mount -t sysfs /sys /tmp/mnt/sys/
mount -t proc /proc /tmp/mnt/proc/
mount –bind /dev /tmp/mnt/dev/
mount –bind /dev/pts /tmp/mnt/dev/pts/
mount –bind /dev/shm /tmp/mnt/dev/shm/
```

Now when I try to run second stage of `debootstrap`:

```
sudo chroot ./ ./debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

I get the following error message:

```
W: Failure trying to run:  /sbin/ldconfig
W: See //debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details
```

I checked the `debootstrap/debootstrap.log`:

```
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped 
Segmentation fault
```

Indeed when I try `sudo chroot ./ ./sbin/ldconfig` I get same Seg fault.
But when I try `sudo chroot ./ ./bin/bash` it works.

I am not sure what should be my next step.

I guess it is something related to my qemu config or verison (I am using `version 2.8.1(Debian 1:2.8+dfsg-6+deb9u4)`). I checked many threads about similar issues, but I could not find one which would help me to find the solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention I use `Raspbian` OS:
`Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch), Release: 9.4`

Comment: Just had a similar issue, albeit in a Docker environment (x86_64 host). I ran some tests with two guest architectures (armhf and arm64) and three Debian releases (bullseye, buster and stretch) both as host and guest OS. Result: the host OS does not seem to have an influence on results; the factor seems to be a combination of guest release and guest architecture. Only the bullseye/arm64 guest is throwing errors. With armhf, all releases (including bullseye) work; with buster or stretch, both architectures (including arm64) work. (I also tested bullseye/i386 on bullseye, which also worked.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think I figured it out.

It works when I select `stretch` as Debian version in `debootstrap` command.

```
sudo debootstrap --foreign --arch i386 stretch  ./ http://deb.debian.org/debian/
```

Now when I think about it more, it makes sense. I guess running i386 Debian in chroot does not provide full separation from host OS (I mounted `proc`, `sys`, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem running Raspbian Buster; the problem went away when chrooting Debian Stretch.

So somehow ldconfig from the i386 repository is not working with the qemu-i386-static emulator on buster, but it IS working on stretch!

Has nothing to do with the host system....